# Why is the front page different on the web versus mobile app?

Tags: support, android-app, homepage, algorithm, web

I've noticed that the front page of SE sites is different depending on whether you're viewing it using the mobile app or the web app.

These screenshots were taken at the same time.

[image]
[image]

The "At smaller, graduated sites" proposal appeared in the mobile app due to an answer being submitted. However, it never appeared in the web app. I'm guessing this is because it's below a threshold for negative score. However, why is it different in the mobile app?

By the way, I know that I would see it if I went to "questions" and selected "active".

So, the question is: Is there a different algorithm for the list of front page questions on web versus the mobile site? And why is that? (I'm not saying it's a bad idea, I'm just curious as to why.)

Note that the "We are updating jQuery" question did appear in the web a while after the screenshot was taken. I'm not sure why it took a little longer to appear there, but that doesn't seem to matter much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MSE, questions with a score of -8 or lower are omitted from appearing. It has been like this for a while. On non-meta sites the threshold is -4.

This limit has never existed on either versions of the app. All questions, regardless of score, appear on the list.